# How to add search.asmx web reference to webpart application in VS2008 ? facing problem

Tags: visual-studio, search, service, moss

I am trying to create the custom search webpart. I want to use Enterprise Search Query Model (MOSS) . But unable to add the web reference of the search.asmx webservice. infact it has no WSDL file. just wondering about what setting it needs.... too If anybody know how to do, same. please let me know. you can find the search webservice at

**Edited :** "http://server_name:port_no/sites/site_name/_vti_bin/search.asmx"

I tried by right cliking on project said Add Service Reference , inserts the url said Go , but nothis was there. same i tried with web aplication . but no effect. even i can see the methods in browser, but cannot generate WSDL ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. browse searchwsdl.aspx in browser. it generates the wsdl (xml) format file. just give the web reference to the application. that it.

Comment: You can also use: http://Server_Name/_vti_bin/search.asmx?wsdl which is the standard for getting the WSDL :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong url.

`http://PORTAL/_vti_bin/spsearch.asmx` is for WSS3.

`http://PORTAL/_vti_bin/search.asmx` is for MOSS.

[Also check out a test tool for searching SharePoint 2007](http://www.mosssearch.com/searchwebservice.html).

Comment: Please see once. I cannot use third party tools for my company security policy. I was given wrong URL in my question. Please review once again. Please guide me

Comment: Can you surf to the url in your browser?

Comment: yes , and i am getting view of service ,can view:

QueryService

Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 Query Web Service

The following operations are supported. For a formal definition, please review the Service Description.
    * GetPortalSearchInfo
    * GetSearchMetadata
    * Query
    * QueryEx
    * RecordClick
    * Registration
    * Status

Comment: If you type: http://PORTAL/_vti_bin/search.asmx?wsdl, then does it work?

Could it be a problem that the user you are running VS under does not have permission to the MOSS server?

Comment: What does that mean : PORTAL/ here ?? I I have to put server_name:port_no/sites/site_name there? If yes , Then I tried with this. I am not properly getting your URL.

Comment: server:port/_vti_bin/search.asmx?wsdl - do it on the root site, not on the subsite. (PORTAL=server)